# How do I get my delete function to work in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am in the process of developing a website and I have run into a few problems. I am very new to coding so pardon my novice, but I am having a hard time creating a functional delete user button. When I click delete, It takes me to the delete url, but does not delete from my home table or mysql database. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that should pertain to the question.

Home Page Table;

```
<template>
  <div class="between:flex bottom:margin-3">
    <div class="center: flex-items">
      <span class="right:margin-1">Show</span>
      <select v-model="currentEntries" class="select" @change="paginateEntry">
        <option v-for="se in showEntries" :key="se" :value="se">
          {{ se }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <span class="left:margin-1">Entries</span>
      <div class="end:flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tableHolderDiv">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Location</th>
          <th scope="col">End User</th>
          <th scope="col">Order Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Application</th>
          <th scope="col">Service Tech</th>
          <th scope="col">Department</th>
          <th scope="col">Hours</th>
          <th scope="col">Travel Hours</th>
          <th scope="col">Contact Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Reason</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="row in serviceEntries"
          :key="row.id"
          @click="alertID(row.id)"
        >
          <th scope="row">{{ row.id }}</th>
          <td>{{ row.location }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.end_user }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.order_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.application }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.service_tech }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.department }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.hours }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.travel_hours }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.contact_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.reason }}</td>
          <a
            href="/delete/{{this.id}}"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-light btn-small"
            onclick="event.stopPropagation(); return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');"
            ><i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete</a
          >
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ServiceTable",
  computed: {
    serviceEntries() {
      return this.$store.state.serviceEntries;
       
    },
  },
  methods: {
    alertID(id) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: `/modify/${id}`,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The only Delete Call; in my app.js

```
app.delete("/api/service/:id", (req, res) => {
  // console.log("DELETE /api/user/" + req.params.id + " called");
  pool.query(
    "DELETE FROM `master` WHERE id = ?",
    [req.params.id],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) res.json(error);
      else res.json(results);
    }
  );
});
```

Do I possibly need to add an app.post for delete?

Answer (score 0):

`a` tag is using GET-request and you need DELETE-request. Use `button` and a handler in which you can use some package like `axios` or `got` to make such requests (and other GET, POST, PUT).

```html
<button
  class="btn btn-light btn-small"
  onclick="onDelete">
  <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
  Delete
</button>
```

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  methods: {
    async onDelete() {
      if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?') {
        return
      }
      await axios.delete(`/delete/${this.id}`);
    },
    alertID(id) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: `/modify/${id}`,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using axios and I tried the above code, but no cigar. My code takes me to my specified delete url whilst the code you graciously provided takes me to my edit page somehow.

Comment: At least you need to indicate a API route like `/api/service/${this.id}` (if you already set base URL in axios defaults) instead of `/delete/${this.id}` in `axios.delete` call. I just indicated it using your URL in a template.